# Task failed while writing rows

Tags: apache-spark

My spark version is 1.6.2. My code is

```
val phoneDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
    Map("url" -> "jdbc:db2://127.0.0.1:50000/FERTDD",
      "driver" -> "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver",
      "user" -> "fwetergfdv",
      "password" -> "fdgergtt",
      "dbtable" -> "dsfewrrte")).load()
  phoneDF.write.parquet("hdfs://hadoop:9000/db2/dfgtt/dsfewrrte.parquet")
```

But I have got the wrong is

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows 
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
```

But some table is OK,I do not know why.Any help is appreciate.

Comment: Its OK to get such error, Ideally with fault tolerance your job should get done. Is it not?

Comment: no,My job is break off

Answer (score 0):

java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException is thrown if any character is not legal for given charset. Check the file encoding using

```
System.getProperty("file.encoding");
```

You can set encoding using environment variable like

```
export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

Comment: My file encoding is UTF-8.So it is no problem.Any suggestions?